# Weighted Arithmetic Mean, with 2 or more weights per observation

Tags: average, means, descriptive-statistics

I'm NOT asking about the "usual" weighted arithmetic mean where each observation $x_i$ has an associated weight $w_i$, and the weighted arithmetic mean of the series is defined as:

$\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_i{w_ix_i}}{\sum_i{w_i}}$

---

Instead, what if there are 2 or more weights associated with each observation, i.e. instead of an Nx1 vector of weights for the Nx1 vector of observations, there is now an NxM matrix of weights.

I can transform each of the individual weight column vectors to be normalized by dividing by the sum of that vecotr of weights (so each element in a given column of the matrix is divided by the sum of that column). But then if I naively combined the weights as follows, I would essentially just be taking a a weighted arithmetic mean of the product of the weights, which isn't necessarily what I want:

$\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_i(\prod_j{{w_{ij})x_i}}}{\sum_i(\prod_j{{w_{ij})}}}$, e.g. for 2 weights per observation:
$\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_i{{w_{i1}w_{i2}x_i}}}{\sum_i{{w_{i1}w_{i2}}}}$

Is there a standard way of dealing with a weighted arithmetic mean when each observation has 2 to N weights?

Comment: Are you sure you have more weights? It does not seem right. Could you give us some details about the way you arrived at this description of your data?

Comment: well, it is kind of funny, I never saw this kind of thing before. What is the motivation behind this? I mean, what kind of problem are you facing now then you have to deal with 'double weighted' average? May be it will help us to understand better

Comment: Well, I guess I don't really need to have multiple weights, but potentially could if it helped, and was wondering if there is a good way to deal with it. I have N "observations". I can weight them by the number of occurrences of that observation, but I also have other information for each observation. For instance, I have some measure of the impurity of each observation (an "observation" includes the counts of a related few items, so I can calculate e.g. the entropy for each observation, and could weight lower entropy observations more heavily than higher entropy observations).

Comment: You are in fact just modifying the weights, and that is just a weighed mean problem in the end

Comment: So then since I'm basically creating a single modified weight, should I perform a regular weighted arithmetic mean, but the weights are some function g(#occurrences, purity)? E.g. in the simplest case mentioned in my question, g(#occurrences, purity) could just be the product of the two terms, and you would get the 2nd equation above for $\bar{x}$ .